# How does this particular daniweb page get 208 pageview although there was no search volume for this keywords- usage get method arrays?

Tags: google-search-console, seo, page

How does this particular daniweb page get 208 pageview although there was no search volume for this keywords- usage get method arrays?

daniweb page : http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/java/threads/378417

Search volume is none for - usage get method arrays.

When I search in google keyword tool.

Answer (score 1):

Users can reach this page thanks to several different source, including a direct link like the one shared in your question.

For each person that requests the page, the page view is incremented. It has nothing to do with search volume. Also, search volume in Google Keyword Tool doesn't return a value for very low traffic keywords. But remember, very low traffic doesn't necessary mean zero traffic.